# ViewModel that is being posted back to the controller - all members are null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm trying to post back the model to the controller, but the members within the ViewModel are null (rather than the entire model just being null).  This is the View Model:

```
public List<ApplicationDetails> ApplicationDetails { get; set; }
public Application Application { get; set; }
public SelectList[] Match { get; set; }
public SelectList[] States { get; set; }
```

This is the controller action's signature:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Details(ApplicationQueueDetailsViewModel applicationQueueDetailsViewModel)
```

This is the Form Signature:

```
<%
    using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "ApplicationQueue", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        ...etc
        <input type="Submit" value="Save Status" id="Submit1" />
%>
```

This is an old application that I'm attempting to refactor a little bit.  I've obviously left some stuff out.  I'm not sure what else to include.

Any thoughts as to why Application, Application Details, Match, and States are all null during the controller post?I feel like it's something simple I'm overlooking

Comment: you need to be more specific and maybe start out with a smaller, simpler viewmodel .. I'm not even sure what the purpose of an array of selectlists would be.

Comment: If its not binding, it means the code in your view is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your inputs have matching name fields.